# How To properly release Tabbarcontroller from memory after log out

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using tabbarcontroller as initial view controller, I have a logout button in my sidemenu, So after logout, Changing window.rootviewcontroller to login screen. So I thought My dash board is not in memory now, But it exists still in memory because deinit() is not called

```
class DashBoardViewController:UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

deinit {
    print("Deallocated dashboard")
}

}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Use ARC and no problem.

Comment: @GeneCode I'm Using ARC

Comment: Then u dont need to care about releasing anything.

Comment: How are you removing the tab bar controller from the hierarchy?

Comment: @Fogmeister  window.rootVc = tabbar controller, after logout window.rootVc = Login, If i change the root vc  the previous Vc will be  there ?

Comment: Are you holding a reference to the tab bar anywhere? Like in a property or something?

Comment: @Fogmeister Im using https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController Where my dashboard is front view controller, and my logout is there side menu(Rear view controller)

Comment: If your vcs in the tab bar use timers etc, then those timers likely hold on to the vcs. You need to make sure all sub vcs stop using timers and such things. My current approach is to have a `tearDown` function in each of the vcs contained by the tab bar vc, and call that on each of them. The tearDown() function will contain stuff like invalidating and nilling out timers, stopping KVO, NotificationCenter observing etc.

Comment: seems to you have a strong reference in your "DashBoardViewController:UITabBarController" and when you fix it this problem will not be happen